# Java 8 type inference error, assigning lambda expression to a variable of type Object

Tags: lambda, casting, java-8, type-inference

Why is the java compiler complaining about the first statement, it's because the expression `() -> ""` doesn't have a definite type, i mean it could be a `Supplier <String>` or a custom functional interface type, etc ... ?

```
Object emptyStringBuilder = () -> ""; // causes compiler error

Object emptyStringBuilder = (Supplier<String>)() -> "";
```

Could you elaborate on the exact causes please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type inference for a lambda expression happens *from the target type*, meaning when you write something like this for example:

```
 () -> "";
```

That is indeed a `Supplier` (to you, not the compiler), *but* what if I have a type declared like this:

```
static interface Producer<T> {
    T produce();
}
```

This means that your lambda could be a `Producer` or a `Supplier`. Thus assigning has to be to a `@FunctionalInterface` (or casting) so that type inference could happen.

In the `JLS` these are defined as poly expressions (they depend on the context in which they are used - like generics, method reference, ternary operator)

Answer (score 4):

Lambda expression implements [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) - an interface with just a single public non-static and non-default method. In the first case compiler gets type from the left side - `Object`, because it cannot infer a type of your lambda expression. Compiler wont pick any interface for you. And `Object` does not implement functional interface, so compiler complains about this situation.

In second case you use functional interface `Supplier<T>` and you assign it to an `Object` which is correct in terms of compilation - compiler is satisfy because you cast down your specific type (`Supplier<T>` in that case) to a most general `Object` (every class inherits from `Object` class).

Comment: a variable of type object could be pointing to functional interface no ? i think the cause of the errors comes from the compiler cannot infer the exact type of the right hand side expression which could be pointing to any functional interface having the signature of its abstract method as "String someName ()" no ?

Comment: Correct. Compiler cannot infer exact type because empty lambda expression might be represented by multiple different functional interfaces. Java as statically compiled language has to know exact type at compilation level and it cannot pick right type for you. This is how I understand it.